# Parse CDATA fields in xmlToList

Tags: xml, r, cdata

I'm having trouble with `xmlToList`, specifically several CDATA fields in an API response.

I'm working with an API that returns either XML or JSON. I'm using `XML::xmlToList` to translate the XML-formatted API response into a list structure and **RJSONIO**'s `fromJSON` to do the same with the JSON format.

The `fromJSON` output is exactly what I want but I want to be able to get the same structure from the XML response.

The main issue is that `xmlToList` seems to discard the contents of fields if they're inside a `CDATA` wrapper.

Here's an example URL for the API (in XML):
http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106

And here's one in JSON: http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106?format=json

As you can see in the first link, there are several fields with values stored in `CDATA`, like `title`.

```
<title>
<![CDATA[ wet dirt ]]>
</title>
```

If I parse this with `fromJSON`, I get the following:

```
List of 17
 $ id         : num 903893
 $ title      : chr "wet dirt"
 $ userName   : chr "jessicabrown"
 $ numViews   : num 323
 $ numVotes   : num 1
 $ numComments: num 0
 $ numHearts  : num 0
 $ rank       : num 0
 $ dateCreated: chr "2008-03-17 11:22:21"
 $ hex        : chr "6B4106"
 $ rgb        :List of 3
  ..$ red  : num 107
  ..$ green: num 65
  ..$ blue : num 6
 $ hsv        :List of 3
  ..$ hue       : num 35
  ..$ saturation: num 94
  ..$ value     : num 42
 $ description: chr ""
 $ url        : chr "http://www.colourlovers.com/color/6B4106/wet_dirt"
 $ imageUrl   : chr "http://www.colourlovers.com/img/6B4106/100/100/wet_dirt.png"
 $ badgeUrl   : chr "http://www.colourlovers.com/images/badges/c/903/903893_wet_dirt.png"
 $ apiUrl     : chr "http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106"
```

The `title` field is just a character string, as desired. But using `xmlToList`, I get:

```
List of 17
 $ id         : chr "903893"
 $ title      :List of 1
  ..$ : NULL
 $ userName   :List of 1
  ..$ : NULL
 $ numViews   : chr "323"
 $ numVotes   : chr "1"
 $ numComments: chr "0"
 $ numHearts  : chr "0"
 $ rank       : chr "0"
 $ dateCreated: chr "2008-03-17 11:22:21"
 $ hex        : chr "6B4106"
 $ rgb        :List of 3
  ..$ red  : chr "107"
  ..$ green: chr "65"
  ..$ blue : chr "6"
 $ hsv        :List of 3
  ..$ hue       : chr "35"
  ..$ saturation: chr "94"
  ..$ value     : chr "42"
 $ description:List of 1
  ..$ : NULL
 $ url        :List of 1
  ..$ : NULL
 $ imageUrl   :List of 1
  ..$ : NULL
 $ badgeUrl   :List of 1
  ..$ : NULL
 $ apiUrl     : chr "http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106"
```

Instead of returning either `<![CDATA[ wet dirt ]]>` or `wet dirt`, as I would expect, I just get a single-element list with `NULL` contents. How can I get `xmlToList` to handle the `CDATA` elements?

Here's the code:

```
xmlurl <- url('http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106')
response1 <- paste(readLines(xmlurl, warn=FALSE), collapse='')
close(xmlurl)

jsonurl <- url('http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106?format=json')
response2 <- paste(readLines(jsonurl, warn=FALSE), collapse='')
close(jsonurl)

str(XML::xmlToList(response1))
str(RJSONIO::fromJSON(response2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `XML:::parserOptions`

Use

```
test <- xmlParse("http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/6B4106", options = NOCDATA)
res <- xmlToList(test)

> res$color$title
[1] "wet dirt"
>
```